# Save file directly to specified path without showing save or open dialogue

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, web-scraping

I'm invoking javascript in a web page using

```
webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("download_file");`.
```

This javascript opens dialogue asking user to save or open the file. I want to save the file directly to the path without showing the dialogue to user. How can i achieve this. I'm scraping the web page. I'm extracting the required details from the web page.

**download_file()**:

```
function download_file() {
    var summaryFlag = 0;
    if (document.getElementById("frmincludefilesummary").checked) {
        summaryFlag = 1;
    }
    url = '/filedatabase/file_process_request.html?mru=53616c7&type=doc';
    url += '&sum=' + summaryFlag + '&logo=0&xcode=name&serve_txt=0&folderid=';
    document.location = url;
}​
```

Comment: are you positive its not the browser triggering the prompt?

Comment: I didn't get you Matt Lo. The command above is invoking the java script. Java script is given below.
    `function download_file() {
    var summaryFlag     = 0;
    if(document.getElementById("frmincludefilesummary").checked){
 summaryFlag=1;
    }


     url = '/filedatabase/file_process_request.html?mru=53616c7&type=doc';
    url += '&sum='+summaryFlag+'&logo=0&xcode=name&serve_txt=0&folderid=';
    document.location   = url;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are trying to achieve is not possible. Javascript cannot access or write to the client filesystem directly. If allowed it would be a huge security breach.

Alternate options would be to make use of flash or java or activeX.